# Angular Not import JS when using AOT

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application - I imported js

```
import './components/print/Print';
import './components/file/File';
import './components/print/custom';
```

file in **app.module** it's working when ng build , but when using  `"optimization": true , "aot": true, "buildOptimizer": true`
not working

it's correct way to import this file ? how can fix this ?

App module :

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, InjectionToken, } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule, } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormIOComponent} from './formio.component';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import { FormioModule } from 'angular-formio';
import {routerConfig} from './app.router';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { HttpServices } from './services/http.services';
import { Globals } from './services/global.service';
import { NgxUiLoaderModule } from  'ngx-ui-loader';
//import { Liferay } from './model/liferay.model';
import '../styles.css';
import './components/print/Print';
import './components/file/File';
import './components/print/custom';

import { UserProfile } from './services/user.profile.service';
import { NgxSpinnerModule } from 'ngx-spinner';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
@NgModule({
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule, 
    ReactiveFormsModule, 
    FormioModule, 
    HttpModule, 
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    NgxUiLoaderModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routerConfig) ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, FormIOComponent],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
  providers:[HttpServices,Globals,UserProfile,{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue : '/' }
  //{ provide:Liferay, useValue: (<any>window).PORTAL},
  ]
})
export class AppModule { 
  constructor(){
  }
}
```

custom.js

```
/**
 * This file shows how to create a custom component and register that within an Angular application.
 *
 * Get the base component class by referencing Formio.Components.components map.
 */
import { environment } from '../../../environments/environment';
import ButtonComponent from 'formiojs/components/button/Button';
import Components from 'formiojs/components/Components';
import HTMLComponent from 'formiojs/components/html/HTML';

import PrintEditForm from './Print.form';
import { Formio } from 'formiojs';
/**
 * Create a new CheckMatrixComponent "class" using ES5 class inheritance notation.
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance
 *
 * Here we will derive from the base component which all Form.io form components derive from.
 *
 * @param component
 * @param options
 * @param data
 * @constructor
 */



export default class CustomHTMLComponent extends HTMLComponent {

  setHTML() {
    console.log("Called");
    this.htmlElement.innerHTML = this.interpolate(this.t(this.component.content));
  }




}
Components.setComponent('htmlelement', CustomHTMLComponent);
```

Comment: Define "not working"

Comment: @Igor for example custom,js override method **setHTML()**  when build without **aot** work but with **aot** not override

Comment: What is `Components.setComponent('htmlelement', CustomHTMLComponent);`?

Comment: @Phix it's method used to set html component  this is source link :https://github.com/formio/formio.js/blob/master/src/components/Components.js